# number with decimal places to allow commas in regular expression validation

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using a regular expression in javascript as

```
/^\s*?(\d+(\.\d{1,2})?|\.\d{1,2})\s*$/
```

This is used to check for *numbers upto 2 decimal places*, like **200.45**.

I also need to allow *more than one commas* like **1,000.45** or **2,00,455.76**

Please note this expression also allows numbers like **.1 , 1.2** .

How can this be achieved the above regular expression. Thanks

Comment: The first d `/^\s*?(\ HERE d+` matches the digits. So just rewrite it to match commas also.

Comment: Money format http://stackoverflow.com/a/15967976/731947 ?

Comment: Thanks i got the solution. I have posted the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks I got the above expression working as.

```
var regexp =/^\s*?([\d\,]+(\.\d{1,2})?|\.\d{1,2})\s*$/;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern:

```
/\b\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*(\.\d{1,2})?\b/
```

Comment: Thanks i got the solution. I have posted the same.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what i can think of the regular expression : 
`^(\d?\d?\d(,\d\d\d)*|\d+)(\.\d\d)?$`

I have not run it, but you can try it out.

Comment: Thanks i got the solution. I have posted the same.