# Price field validation using javascript either jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a price field in my form i should allow decimal or floating point numbers only , not characters and any other special and white spaces in my price field.

How could i get that?

This is my code :

```
    $("#foo").blur(function() {
    var price = $("#foo").value;
    var validatePrice = function(price) {
   return /^(\d*([.,](?=\d{3}))?\d+)+((?!\2)[.,]\d\d)?$/.test(price);
}
    alert(validatePrice(price)); // False
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T32KD/)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15958808/regexp-for-validating-price

Comment: No need for Regex if you are using HTML5: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/6djkS/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First off,  here's the corrected code:

```
$("#foo").blur(function() {
    var price = $("#foo").val();
    var validatePrice = function(price) {
      return /^(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+)(?:\.\d+)?$/.test(price);
    }
    alert(validatePrice(price)); // False
});
```

You will need to test for empty values (undefined) separately.  Also,  if you want to allow negative values use:

```
/^-?(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+)(?:\.\d+)?$/.test(price);
```

This regular expression was lifted from the JQuery Validate plug-in by Jörn Zaefferer.  I recommend you consider using that plug-in as it contains a lot of other features.

Answer (score 3):

In HTML5 it [supports checking validity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement#Methods) natively if the browser supports it:

```
$("#foo").blur(function(){
    alert(this.checkValidity());
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/6djkS/

---

You can always fall back to the good old ugly Regex if the browser does not support it.

Basing on the Number definition used in JSON:

[image]
<sub>(source: [json.org](http://www.json.org/number.gif))</sub>

(with the negative, scientific notation parts removed.)

```
var regex = /^\d*(.\d{2})?$/;
regex.test(price);   //Boolean
```

Answer (score 0):

For https://stackoverflow.com/a/21494842/1885344, the correct regex would be

```
var regex = /^\d*(\.\d{2})?$/;
regex.test(price);   //Boolean
```

As it is now, it would permits all character as the decimal separator where as it should be only dot (.) character.